# i have aes security issue after uploading my script to database

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, aes

I am working on a Proof of Concept for a project, I am send some data from android to mysql database and also fetch some data from mysql database to android. I have succesfully done this through a php script and it is working when i used a local host ip but it gives me invalid json when i hosted it on a web server. I think it is AES security issue. I am using retrofit2 to make the request. Below is my code for making the retrofit request.

```
//Creating a retrofit object
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(RetrofitApi.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) //Here we are using the GsonConverterFactory to directly convert json data to object
            .build();

    //creating the api interface
    RetrofitApi api = retrofit.create(RetrofitApi.class);

    //now making the call object
    //Here we are using the api method that we created inside the api interface
    Call<ClientList> call = api.getClient();

    //then finallly we are making the call using enqueue()
    //it takes callback interface as an argument
    //and callback is having two methods onRespnose() and onFailure
    //if the request is successfull we will get the correct response and onResponse will be executed
    //if there is some error we will get inside the onFailure() method
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ClientList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ClientList> call, Response<ClientList> response) {

            //In this point we got our client list
            //thats damn easy right ;)
            final ClientList clientList = response.body();

            Log.v("Retrofit Response", response.body().toString());
            Log.v("Test", "" + clientList.getClientList().size());
            //now we can do whatever we want with this list
            ClientRecyclerAdapter adapter = new ClientRecyclerAdapter(clientList.getClientList(), MainActivity.this);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Client client = clientList.getClientList().get(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SiteActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("client_id", client.getId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ClientList> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

and this is the script that handles the encoding the json

```
 <?php
/*
 * Following code will get all the 
 clients in the database
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';



//this function help us to get all client
//clients table
function getAllClient($db){
    $response["clients"] = array();
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM clients");
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(($row_count = $stmt->rowCount()) > 0){
         $response["clients"] = $rows;
        echo json_encode($response); 
    }else{
        // no client found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No client found in the database";

            // echo no client JSON
            echo json_encode($response);        
    }
    //$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();

} 
 getAllClient($connection);

?>
```

When I tested the API on a web browser it returned a json which passed the green test on a JSONFormatter. How can the AES security be handled to get a properly formatted JSON that retrofit2(Android) can handle.

Comment: whats the response that your webserver gives? and the status code of the response?

Comment: Thanks @petey the web server seems OK, it echos a nicely formatted json but i think that is because the web browser is javascript friendly, it knows how to handle the AES but android doesn't.